# Group by Time where Time is in date column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
ID         Date
1          2013-01-11 00:57:25 
2          2013-02-01 02:17:05 
3          2013-02-05 03:12:23
4          2013-02-17 10:17:02
5          2013-02-19 11:27:25
6          2013-02-27 13:42:13
7          2013-03-09 15:57:25
8          2013-03-12 16:00:00
9          2013-04-10 19:39:18
10         2013-05-16 20:46:38
```

I want to `Group ID` according to time in this table. Remember that date is in one column, so can I take only time from **date column and group** it according to different times.

Like I want `ID` from time `00:00:00 to 12:00:00` in one group and from `12:00:00 to 24:00:00` in another group in `mysql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TIME(`Date`) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '12:00:00' THEN 'early' ELSE 'late' END AS myTime,
COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY myTime
```

You can also add multiple "groups" easily:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TIME(`Date`) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '03:00:00' THEN '0-3' 
CASE WHEN TIME(`Date`) BETWEEN '03:00:01' AND '06:00:00' THEN '3-6'
ELSE 'later' END AS myTime,
COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY myTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

```
SELECT HOUR(Date), COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY HOUR(Date);
```